# Add some text between AppBar and TabBar

Tags: flutter, tabbar, appbar

I want to create view like this : [image]

My question is, how to add the text between AppBar and TabBar. I was try to put tabbar inside column and just get blank view.

My code :

`***https://pastebin.com/Ryd8bxHp***`

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexibleSpace property:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html

[image]

Comment: can we add some text in flexibleSpace?